# Gzip compression in PHP through SOAP Api

Tags: php, soap

I want to get response from soap in compressed format so that fetching time will be reduce. I get only plain xml response.

I have tried to put http request to 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip'. That dont work. I am running PHP 7 and nginx.

```
$exoport = new SoapClient('www.example.com/Export.asmx?wsdl',array(
       'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'stream_context'=>stream_context_create(
            array('http'=>
              array(
                   'protocol_version'=>'1.0',
                'header' => 'Connection: Close',
                   'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | 
            SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP | SOAP_COMPRESSION_DEFLATE
             )
           )
        )
   ));
```

I get only xml responses in plain text. Is there any method to get file in compressed format?

Comment: What are your `Accept` headers?

Comment: Accept-Encoding: gzip

Comment: You could try `Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip;q=1.0, *;q=0.5` to test if it makes any difference. Also are you sure the server can compress and is willing to?